# Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()

Tags: php, magento

I upgraded to `Magento CE 1.9.1` from `Magento CE 1.9.0` and encountering the following issue:

When going to `Customers > Manage Customers` and trying to edit one customer, I get a blank page, with the admin header and footer, but nothing in the middle.

So, I edited the `index.php` page, to `uncomment` the log level, and manage to get the error message:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword() in /includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account.php on line 205**

I checked the file, and did a difference check between the files coming with the version 1.9.0 and the version 1.9.1, it looks like the method `getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()` has been added in the latest version.

I would appreciate your help in trying to solve it.

Comment: In my unedited 1.9.1 ce I do have this method on the customer helper `public function getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_REQUIRE_ADMIN_USER_TO_CHANGE_USER_PASSWORD);
    }`. Do you have an overwrite of this maybe in `app/code/local` ? Or was something changed in your core files ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem could be a few things.

Firstly the simplest is that you either need to refresh your cache or if you have compilation mode active then refresh that.

If that does not fix it then I would suggest you have a local copy of the class `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` and so the code is not picking up the helper for 1.9.1 but the older version.

Have a look under `app/code/local` and see if you have a `Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php`.

My suggestion here is to rather than use local rewrites of core classes either work with config.xml rewrites or find the appropriate events that can be hooked onto and make the changes you need there.